# The current npm install location C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm requires admin privileges to install a package

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating `cordova` app using visual studio 2015, it was working fine till last month.
I have updated the node and npm by downloading it from website.
now when i try to build the app it is giving me below error message.
I have tried whatever i can, but not able to fix the issue.
kindly help me to fix this as it is causing delay in my project delivery.

Error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error

> The current npm install location C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm requires admin privileges to install a package. To resolve the issue, either change the ACL for C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm or change the install path by running 'npm config set prefix %AppData%\npm' and restarting Visual Studio in order to build without being an admin.    eInspection D:\eInspectionBuild\eInspection\eInspection\RUNMDAINSTALL   1

1) I have tried changing node js location into tools-->option-->external web tool
2) also tried reinstalling vs

Answer (score 0):

For the past 2 weeks I have been upgrading a cordova 7 to 12, basically to comply with the Android 12 and 13 requirements regarding local and push notifications, after upgrading cordova and the required plugins I was able to build using the cordova command, but NOT via Visual Studio. I was getting the same error stated above.

After doing a lot of digging, I realized that the culprit was a script included with vs-tac 1.0.42 (This is the last version that I found). Keep in mind that Microsoft stopped supporting tools for apache cordova and It does not work with newer versions of node and npm.

I was able to build the Android project doing the following:

1. Locate your vs-tac folder, for me it was C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac
2. Inside the install.js file, locate the checkIfInstallDirectoryIsWritable function
3. The fs.unlink(fileName) function needs a callback as a second parameter, this will solve your permission error:

   ```
   fs.unlink(fileName, function (error) {});
   ```
4. run npm update on the vs-tac folder if you are getting package not found errors.
5. After that I had to update all the unsupported cordova.raw calls for every *.js file contained in the vs-tac folder.

I hope this information is useful for everyone who wished to keep building apps with the updated versions of cordova, node and npm.

These are the specs of my environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 14.0.25431.01
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova Update 10
- Node 16.13.2
- npm 8.1.2
- cordova-cli 12.0.0
- cordova-android 12.0.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).